# C++, Array of objects VS array of pointers pointing to those objects

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Consider a c++ class named **A**. What are the pros/cons to use an array of objects:

```
std::array<A, 10>
```

instead of an array of pointers:

```
std::array<A*, 10>
```

Comment: Do you prefer Apples or Oranges ? It all depends on what you want to do.

Comment: They're totally different. What do you think?

Comment: If you are going from Java to C++, I would suggest that you read a tutorial about pointers. That will probably clear up questions like this.

Comment: @Skaarjasaurus I have just finished reading the chapter concerning pointers and array in Accelerated C++ and I have this basic question in my head. I could not find any answers on google (or at least I was not able to google the right words)

Comment: Compared to Java, one uses `new` a lot less often, and with modern versions of C++, the use of smart pointers, etc. should remove most needs of using "raw" pointers.

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason not to, use the former. If you need the latter, consider `std::array<std::unique_ptr<A>, 10>`

Comment: Why is my question downvoted? Should I edit it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are important differences:

Array of objects:

- Memory of the objects is managed by `std::array`.
- Objects are stored in contiguous memory (good cache efficiency)
- All objects are of same type
- All objects exist
- Assigning an element makes a copy of the object

Array of pointers:

- Memory of the objects that are pointed to is not managed by the `std::array` which contains the pointers.
- You can store pointers to a common base of polymorphic types
- Pointers can have `nullptr` value i.e. does not point to any object
- Assigning an element does not make a copy of the object which is pointed to

Whether any of these things is a pro or a con depends on your use case.

And now for the opinion based part, as a hint to beginners: In my opinion, the fact that the memory is managed by the array makes it clear that the array "owns" the objects. It's often not clear who owns the objects that are pointed to by the pointers. The clarity of ownership, combined with the cache efficiency which is always a bonus, makes the array of objects a good default choice when you are not sure. Use objects in arrays when you can, pointers when you need to. And when you need pointers, consider whether `std::unique_ptr` is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use STL array,  you can use your own array

1) A array[10]

or

2) A* array[10]

For #1, class A must have a default constructor.

```
    A needs more memory to hold object

    Whenever you assigned an object to any index of the array, copy constructor gets called

    Compilation time required is more
```

For #2 There is no need of constructor

```
   sizeof(array) = size of pointer * 10

   compilation time required is less

   There is no need of default constructor or copy constructor
```

Comment: Would you explain, how the array of pointers reduce compilation time, please. Also, it might be worth noting that there is no need for a default constructor if you use an initializer list with parameters for non-default constructors (requires a compiler with support for the current standard). Also worth noting that the total memory used by the array and the pointed objects combined is higher for the array of pointers.